# Update a set of records using Row_Number() and/or Cursor and Break When Condition is met- SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table where I want to update CID column until it finds another column value, where EID = 7. I ordered my table Using PID in DESC order.
Here is my table structure.

[image]

After the update the table will look like:

[image]

I basically want to reorder the table by CID, and want to update the top rows (Set CID = 1010 )till it finds where EID = 10. When EID = 10, it will not update the rest beneath, including it,
I tried using Row_Number() the thing is my table contains a different and large number of CID's plus the value of EID for each CID differs, but every CID has where EID = 10. I tried, using cursors, sorting using Row_Number(), but I couldn't fetch the right data. Any help is welcome.

Comment: why 1010? How you got that number? It is for first set upto reaching 10 or what is the pattern to udpate?

Comment: @KannanKandasamy CID = 1010 is the default CID (can be a any random number) that I want to set, to exclude it whenever I fetch data next time.

Comment: Do you have any id to order by?

Comment: What happens if next 10 appears?

Comment: EID - 10 will never be duplicate, and I order by PID (here you see PID not ordered number coz I filtered CID - 11050)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use windowing function and bucket he occurrence of 10 and then update as below:

```
update t 
set t.cid = 1010 
from #table t join
( select *, sum(case when eid = 10 then 1 else 0 end) over(order by pid desc) rown from #table ) r
on t.PId = r.PId
and rown = 0
```

Code as below: https://rextester.com/GUW95636